# Unable to get Bundling/Minification to work in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2012 RC

I have created an ASP.NET 4 Web Application / Internet Application

In a view I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    alert("Test");
  });
</script>
```

In spite of prolonged searching I cannot get Bundling/Minification to work. In _Layout.cshtml I have the following. I have done NOTHING else. Can someone please tell me what I need to do? Many Thanks.

```
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css", "~/Content/css")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

  @*This line Does Not Work*@
  @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/js")

  @*This Line Does Work*@ 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Anyone? I would be grateful if someone could suggest a reason why noone has replied. Is it because the answer is so simple I should be able to work it out for myself, or perhaps I have not explained the problem very well. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: OK, I really have tried and I simply cannot get bundling/minification to include jquery. Perhaps someone could be kind enough to point me to an example that actually works because everything I have read fails. I am obviously missing some simple step! Many thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 4):

First create your script bundle, and add whichever scripts you want.

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-1.*",
        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"));
}
```

Then use @Scripts.Render in you page like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery");
```

Notice that the path I specified in the ScriptBundle above is the same path I used in Scripts.Render.

Follow this article, http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification.

Comment: I am afraid this is not much help Matthew. Your link gives me the impression that I don't have to do anything at all for jQuery to work. Out of interest, would you be kind enough to let me know what YOU did to get jQuery to work using a standard MVC4 project.

Comment: OK I finally seem to have got jQuery to work. In_Layout.cshtml, there is a line that says @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery"). I moved this line to just below the line at the top that says @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr"). I have absolutely no idea why this works but it does. Many thanks Matthew for trying to help.

Comment: Actually if you read the linked article carefully, I think you see you need to create a bundle like, and then use @Scripts.Render to output the scripts. I will edit my answer with further explanation.

Comment: +1 for the link to the bundling and minification article. It helped me understand what was going on and resolve my issue.